# What are these people trying to tell you?

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

These people are trying to tell you something. What is it?

[image: img]

Also, kudos if you can find the pattern between the images...though you'll have to find the pattern to solve this puzzle in the first place.

<sub>**Note:** The text in some of the images are just citations for those that aren't in the public domain. You can ignore them, as they are not part of the puzzle</sub>

Comment: Hopefully I've got the difficulty level right this time ... I just can't seem to nail it.

Comment: No difficulty is wrong. A hard puzzle will be appreciated by some people and avoided by others, and an easy puzzle will be appreciated by some and avoided by others. There is no "perfect" difficulty. What's more, difficulty will vary between users for the same question. I can solve Statue Parks that some people would consider impossible, but I flounder on even the easiest riddles. I'd suggest to stop worrying about difficulty, or how long it takes people to solve your puzzles (which is dependent on who happens to see it, anyhow) and focus on creating high-quality puzzles of any difficulty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the message here is:

> **KUDOS TO YOU**!

The people in the images are:

> US President [John F. Kennedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._Kennedy),
>  Sprinter [Usain Bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usain_Bolt),
>  Naturalist [Charles Darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Darwin),
>  Novelist [George Orwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Orwell),
>  Father of psychoanalysis, [Sigmund Freud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmund_Freud),
>  UK Prime Minister [Margaret Thatcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Thatcher),
>  US politician [Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandria_Ocasio-Cortez),
>  Cosmonaut [Yuri Gagarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Gagarin),
>  US President [Barack Obama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama),
>  Novelist [John Updike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Updike).

To read the hidden message:

> for each picture, we need to take either **the initial of the pictured person's first name or the initial of their surname**. Doing this in a way that makes sense (and uses the hidden 'kudos' hint in the puzzle text) we can get:
>
>  John F. **K**ennedy, **U**sain Bolt, Charles **D**arwin, George **O**rwell, **S**igmund Freud, Margaret **T**hatcher, Alexandria **O**casio-Cortez, **Y**uri Gagarin, Barack **O**bama, John **U**pdike
>
>  In other words, this spells out **KUDOS TO YOU**!

Comment: You got it. Also, the pattern between the images was LFLLFLLFLL, where L is last name initial and F is first name initial. So you don't have to guess which initial to take if you can spot the pattern, but it's quite simple anyways.

Comment: @marsnebulasoup How are you supposed to spot that pattern, exactly? It's not really long enough to be self-evident without lots of guessing. Is it clued somewhere I'm missing?

Comment: @tmpearce - You're right, it's not that evident... I was thinking that if you do find the message, you should be able to spot the pattern if you look for it, but it's not really necessary to solve the puzzle